# range() and in_array() behaviour, what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the code , check output here -> http://codepad.org/7n7dM54e

```
<?php

$key = "a";
$array = range("0","7");
echo "array is : \n";
var_dump($array);
echo "key is : $key \n";
echo "in_array result \n";
var_dump(in_array($key,$array)); // why is it true, 'a' is not a "0" string or 0 int
echo "array_search result \n";
var_dump(array_search($key,$array)); // why is it index 0

?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#102681

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution

`in_array()` and `array_search()` support a type-safe check with the third parameter set to `true`. No conversion will be performed and the values will be compared as is, with type taken into account (like with the `===` operator).

So if you pass `true` at the end of each function call, you'll get the expected results:

```
// Both should return false
var_dump(in_array($key, $array, true));
var_dump(array_search($key, $array, true));
```

---

### Why this is happening

Yep, it's definitely a type conversion, but not one that is specially implemented by `in_array()` or `array_search()`. It's nothing more than the loose comparison performed by the `==` operator.

Both methods call a C function called `php_search_array()`. This function is defined in [`/ext/standard/array.c`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/array.c?revision=306938&view=markup). Here are some of the first few lines:

```
static void php_search_array(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS, int behavior) /* {{{ */
{
    // ---------- snip ----------

    int (*is_equal_func)(zval *, zval *, zval * TSRMLS_DC) = is_equal_function;

    // ...

    if (strict) {
        is_equal_func = is_identical_function;
    }

    // ---------- snip ----------
}
```

If I'm not wrong, the `is_equal_function` you see there simply corresponds to (but may not actually be) the `==` operator, which does a very simple comparison regardless of data type. Type conversion may occur. (Likewise, `is_identical_function` corresponds to `===`.)

For example, `'2abc' == 2` is true, but `'2abc' == 3` is false. This is because comparing a string and an integer causes the string to be cast to integer before comparing. So casting the string `'2abc'` to an int returns 2.

So, like I said below, the same thing applies when you pass `'a'` to both functions: it's being converted to an integer, resulting in `0`, which exists in the array returned by `range()`. And like I said, `range()` returns an array of integers (or floats) whether you pass integers or numeric strings as arguments.

From the [manual entry on PHP's comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is [converted to a number](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and the comparison performed numerically.

---

#### Old "Why is this happening"

I think the internal implementations of `in_array()` and `array_search()` by default try to convert the needle to be of the same type of the elements in the array being searched. If that is the case, since `range()` returns an array of integers, the string `'a'` is converted to an integer, which is `0` and would thus return results for both function calls. Note that `range()` will produce an array of integers or floats even if you pass numbers as strings.

Comment: @BoltClock  why is it that the range is being created as an array of integers when i am giving strings  as lower and upper bounds ?  Also, why is "a" equal to 0 and not its integer ascii value ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak: 1) If you supply numeric strings as arguments to `range()` it will still produce an array of integers, it's just how it's implemented. 2) Casting `(int) 'a'` is not the same as `ord('a')`.

Comment: About that quote from manual - so it says that if `'2abc'` is compared to `'2'`, both are converted to numbers, as `'2'` is *numerical string*? If so, I think it's buggy, because `'2abc' == '2'` returns false.

Comment: @binaryLV: Hmmm, I agree it's kind of of misleading there. The conversion takes place for string == string if and only if **both** operands are numeric strings; if one or both aren't recognized as numeric (see the link within the quote), then they're compared as strings without any conversion.

Comment: @BoltClock, yeah, my bad - it describes situation where *both* strings are numerical, so it's not a bug. Anyway, I have filled a bug report about *documentation problem* with advise to change that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Well , this seems to be a bug with arrays that have a '0' in it

If you change `$array = range("0","7");` to `$array = range("1","7");` , you'll understand what I am trying to say

http://codepad.org/3099zpch

Also read the comment's in the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Not necessarily/only zero values; `var_dump(in_array('1a', range('1', '7')));` also returns true.